# spring-boot spring-mvc apache-commons-fileupload: Required MultipartFile parameter 'file' is not present error

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, apache-commons-fileupload

I'm trying to make the example of this link: https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-uploading-files work with Apcahe `commons-fileupload`but the error: `Required MultipartFile parameter 'file' is not present` is occurring.

The configuration that I'm making on the example is:

1 - Adding the dependency of `commons-fileupload` in the `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

2 - Config the `multipartResolver()` in the `Application.java`

```
@Bean
public MultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
  return new CommonsMultipartResolver();
}
```

Without this configuration everything works fine as Spring is using `org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardServletMultipartResolver` for handle uploads, but I want use `commons-fileupload`.

There is something that I'm missing?

Thanks.

@avaz

Comment: If it works why do you want to use commons-fileupload?

Comment: @M.Deinum, basically for two reasons: 
1 - It's possible to use Spring 4.x with Servlet 2.5 container, which doesn't have support for new Servlet 3.0 Part file uploads, and I have this need. 
2 - Spring documentation says that it's possible [Spring Reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-multipart), I've follow all the instructions in the docs I can't get this working. It could be something that I'm missing or some Spring bug that Spring developers, probably, would like to know about.
Do you know why it isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

You should disable `MultipartAutoConfiguration` like this below:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = MultipartAutoConfiguration.class)
```

Please see the [DOC](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/MultipartAutoConfiguration.html)